# Connecting arduino and EV3 using I2C

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I'm trying to connect arduino uno and ev3 by using this guide (http://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/connecting-ev3-arduino/), 
everything works perfectly but when i tried to use analogRead block to display data from arduino it just displays  i2c address of my arduino.

Comment: Post your code and setup. What is the 'analogRead block'?